# Can't add Android widgets

Tags: android, widget

I am having trouble adding Widgets to my homescreen.

I have created a new, completely empty, page but several app Widgets are not listed.  There are numerous apps I have downloaded and one that I have coded myself, and none of them are appearing in the list of widgets to add.

What possible reason could be causing this? I'm thinking it's either that my phone (Huawei Sonic) is not supported for these particular widgets, which is odd for a dead simple one that I have programmed, or I have disabled something important...

Any suggestions?

UPDATE
As requested here is some code, thanks for the help so far.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.widget"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="Countdown">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>    
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="17:12:34 PM"
    android:textSize="8pt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Posting your code would also prove useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The missing widgets are probably due to the apps being installed on
>   the sdcard. Android prevents these widgets from showing up due to the
>   possible breakages of the widgets when the sdcard is mounted through
>   the usb. Move the apps back to internal and they should show up fine.
>   The same will go for any apps that would have services running or are
>   tied directly into the Android OS (like facebook or gmail).
>
> Oh and the color differences are just when the phone loses
>   connectivity to google's servers. Usually these are tied in with your
>   connectivity through GTalk. Now, why the phone is losing its
>   connectivity, I am not sure. Maybe has to deal with your network
>   signal. Once the network signal drops, it has to wait until it comes
>   back up and then try to sign in again with your google account(s).

http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/24792-widgets-are-not-showing-themselves-on-widget-list/

Answer (score -1):

A widget doesn't get added to home screen if it doesn't find a proper space on the screen.